# Does the law of Demeter also apply to standard ActiveRecord object methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, law-of-demeter

Say you have a class, `Car`, which has a `Driver`. If you wanted to access the driver's age, you would do:

```
@car.driver_age
```

Instead of

```
@car.driver.age
```

If you have delegated the driver's age attribute in the `Car` model (with prefix set to true).

However, if you also had a `Passenger` class and you wanted to access the number of passengers in the car, is the following not breaking the Law of Demeter, or is my thinking over-zealous:

```
@car.passengers.count
```

Comment: over zealous is the term :)

Comment: LoD isn't strictly about the number of dots.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that `count` is so general that i would not find it necessary to proxy the call. I would ask myself the question:

> Is it possible that there will be an implementation of `passengers` in the future, that will not respond to `count`?

Since `passengers` is extremely likely to be a container type forever, and all container types in Ruby (`Array`, `Hash`, …) respond to `count` in the way you would expect, i would answer this question with “no” and therefore stick with `@car.passengers.count`.

EDIT

But if you’re being strict, you are indeed breaking the Law of Demeter. Consider for example a class `RobotCar < Car` that has no passengers at all. Now, following LoD you could simply return `0` from the method `car.passenger_count`, whereas when not following LoD you would have to return an empty container from `passengers` in order not to break other code.

In the end, you will have to decide for yourself just how likely it is that the interface will ever change. If you are very certain that it won't ever change, then i guess it's ok to disobey LoD.

Comment: An empty passenger list could be appropriate, though, since a robot car could have passengers. There's another layer of abstraction, e.g., is it a car *capable* of carrying passengers and merely empty, or is it altogether bereft of seating, which is what this `RobotCar` class implies. Dunno, I'm on the fence-you'd still want to return something reasonable, or throw an exception, if you asked for a robot car's passengers, otherwise your interface will require special checks all over.

Answer (score 1):

If your class/method needs to know the driver's age, it should have a direct reference to the driver:

```
@driver.age
```

Or to the array of passengers:

```
@passengers.count
```

Accessing these through `@car` makes many assumptions. Imagine an automatic car without a driver or a toy car without passengers. `@car.driver_age` or `@car.passengers_count` wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: meh, `driver_age` would be nil, `passengers_count` would be always zero.

Comment: @kch I wouldn't expect a car to know the driver's age in the first place.

Comment: fair. (Dear SO, that's the full length of my comment, thanks for nannying it.)

Comment: @Stefan, indeed but it was a contrived example.

Comment: @railsuser400 sure, it depends, but examining referenced objects usually is a code smell: [Tell, Don't Ask](http://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask).

Answer (score 1):

LoD isn't just "counting dots", and trading an underscore for a dot doesn't help.

- http://haacked.com/archive/2009/07/13/law-of-demeter-dot-counting.aspx
- http://www.dan-manges.com/blog/37

Cars have a driver that have an age; there's nothing unreasonable about this.

(Well, not really, because we're about to enter an age of driverless cars and this model may not account for that, but that's a separate issue.)

> The Law of Demeter for functions requires that a method M of an object O may only invoke the methods of the following kinds of objects:
>
> 1. O itself
> 2. M's parameters
> 3. any objects created/instantiated within M
> 4. O's direct component objects
>
> In particular, an object should avoid invoking
> methods of a member object returned by another method.

Comment: Comments on downvotes are appreciated. I don't find much at fault with the answer,and its claims are backed up.